# Decoding application/json encoded data within XMPP message

Tags: json, http, xmpp

I've been sniffing some XMPP messages from a system that I'm working on, and am getting messages like the following

```
<message to="client@address" type="chat" xml:lang="en" from="server@address/RestApi">
<body>HTTP/1.0 200 OK\nContent-Length:  640\nContent-Type: application/json\nconnection: close\n\n
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
</body></message>
```

I don't really understand what I've got here: it seems to be a XMPP message which is somehow encoding the result of a REST API call that returns JSON. The body of the message seems to be just a HTTP response (basically they seem to have just shoved the HTTP response directly into a XMPP message), but it definitely doesn't look like JSON to me!

I've tried doing a base64 decode of the data within the HTTP response, but it doesn't come up with anything sensible.

Does anyone have any idea how to decode this data? I assume JSON is hidden in there somewhere, but I can't see how or where.

Comment: I suspect application/json is a lie! The content looks like bas64, has all the right characters, and decodes to a nice round 480 bytes. Its either just plain binary or a chunk of something else... No more clues?

Comment: Hmm unfortunately I suspect you're right. No idea why they bothered to put application/json in though! I have a feeling the binary stuff might be an encrypted version of something...I'll have more of a play